# "No Firebase app associated with site" message

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, web-frameworks

While working with Firebase, using:

```
 % firebase experiments:enable webframeworks
```

after running the command below:

```
 % firebase deploy
```

I see this message (that I do not recall seeing before) appear in the terminal:

```
No Firebase app associated with site nice-guy,
injecting project default config.
  You can link a Web app to a Hosting site here
  https://console.firebase.google.com/project/niceguy-5e3c2/settings/general/web
```

I went to the indicated address, but don't know what to do there.

If anyone knows what I am supposed to do relative to the message above I would be glad to get some relevant information.

P.S.

Here is one more detail. I noticed that this issue appears only when I add this line to firebase.json :

```
 "site": "nice-guy",
```

This is not the first time I insert such a line though.

It may have to do with: experiments:enable webframeworks
that I am using almost for the first time.

For reference, on can see below the content of the firebase.json file:

```
% cat firebase.json 
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "site": "nice-guy",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "asia-east1"
    }
  }
}
%
```

Comment: have you connected your site with the firebase hosting ? if not please read [hosting-custom-domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain)

Comment: @Rainy_sidewalks. Well, I have done nothing more, nothing less than what I always do. When running "firebase init hosting" I attach my site to a firebase project. Then inside firebase.json I often add "site": "my-site", to have a URL specific to this site instead of the project-URL. And this  "my-site"  is connected to a web-app inside the firebase project. That's basically all I know.

Comment: please try with running  `firebase init` again or just `firebase init hosting`

Comment: @Rainy_sidewalks. The doc you point is related to custom-domain. But this is not what I need at this point. I am on using things like: https://myniceapp.web.app/

Comment: @Rainy_sidewalks. I ran "firebase init hosting" again as you suggested. I was useful. To see what I noticed, have a second look at my post please. You will see some details I just added at the end.

Comment: i see it ,meanwhile please read [hosting-frameworks-overview](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/frameworks-overview)nand check did you followed all the steps to [install_the_firebase_cli](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli) even if you did all the steps correctly it worth to try them again also best id you 1st logout and then login to cli by `firebase logout` and  `firebase login`

Comment: if you could please post the all the content of the `firebase.json` file

Comment: OK. It's at the end of the post. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

try by making following changes

**1st just try by replacing

`"site": "nice-guy"` with `"site": "niceguy-5e3c2"`  just try.**

**if not resolve then try by removing**

`"source": "."` and `"site": "nice-guy"` then add  `"public":"path to the production folder"` as below

```
{
  "hosting": {
   "public":"path to the production folder most of the case it is in dist/appName"
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "asia-east1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes replacing  "site": "nice-guy" with "site": "niceguy-5e3c2" works but this is not much of a success, since the reason for having "site": "nice-guy" was to avoid the URL: https://niceguy-5e3c2.web.app/.

Comment: sorry to say but you can't change it , it should be as according to the projectNameID  if you want the  [custom-domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) then you must but the domain add then add it with the project [hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting)

Comment: "site": "nice-guy-5e3c2" does not work.

Comment: thanks for confirming .it is all good now after the replace with `niceguy-5e3c2` please try to deploy it with these changes.

Comment: @Rainy_sidewalks. I can change it. I've done it many times before. You can try on your own project. You just need to have set a matching site inside your firebase project. Or to be precise you can change it to https://yourtaste.web.app/ (it cannot arbitrarily chosen of course).

Comment: do you have the site with that name in your project now?

Comment: Yes I do. I've even used it before. This is why I am somewhat puzzled by this error.

Comment: Experimenting shows this is an issue on my local settings, because I can use this same  "site": "nice-guy" from a different local project with no problem. Only if I want to use it from one place I get the problem described in my post. I just have no idea where (in the project) the cause is located.

Comment: so that means in your firebase project you have a hosting site with domain `https://nice-guy.web.app/` . and also another with `https://niceguy-5e3c2.web.app/`  ,is it correct ?

Comment: Yes this can be correct. Though in reality I use only https://nice-guy.web.app/.
And if I have a second local project pointing (with "site": "nice-guy" in firebase.json) to the same  https://nice-guy.web.app/ it will simply overwrite it.

Comment: did you try to `firebase logout` and then reconnect it with cli `firebase init` ,if you do then you will have option to choose the project and then the site (hopefull there you will see `https://nice-guy.web.app/` to select )in from the terminal ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256829/discussion-between-rainy-sidewalks-and-michel).